# Spring boot - Start application with inmemory database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring boot application.
I have it connected to a Postgres database. The URL and login information is in the application.properties file.

This meens that when I am starting the application locally for testing, I need to also have the database up and running. Or else it will fail on startup.

Is there a way to either:

1. Start the application from a test, and use application-test.properties to set the URL and login to a in-memoty database?
2. Or maybe when I start the application locally, that it will change the URL and login information to my in-memory database. Skipping the need to start the application from a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with your option 1: create a test properties config `test/resource/application-test.properties` and annotate the test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

**edit**
If you want to just run the app w/ a different datasource, Spring Profiles is the way to go.

You declare your db config bean in a `@Configuration` class, with the `@Profile` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("mem")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just create a profiled properties file named `application-mem.properties` with your db configuration there.

Finally, you just run your app with a profile like so:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=mem
```

Comment: How do I write the test? I tired writing it by calling the main method, but it only starts the application and exit right away

Comment: @Kims That's the idea behind JUnit - it executes its tasks and then exits. As with everything - think of what you want to do (in this case: test) first and then do it :)

Comment: Just want to start the application normally, but with an in-momory database

Comment: So why can't you just specify this in `application.properties`? What's your question about, again? :)

Comment: Let me try to explain it another way. There is a big chanse I am thinking about this the wrong way.
I have my main method. This starts my application. It will go to my applications.properties file, and get information about my database.

But when I just want to test my application locally, I sometimes dont want to start my database. Sometimes I just want it to be quick, and point to a in-memory database. For example maybe I want to send a request via Postman real quick.

How can I do this, without changing anything in my applications.properties I guess my question is

Answer (score 1):

The below dependency to be added to the pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
         <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.0</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
```

Next, in the application.properties file set the test as active profile.

```
#Profile configuration
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Next, write the application-test.properties as below:

```
#Database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:scratchdb/table_name  
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test

server:
  servlet.context-path: /
  port: 4343

---  
spring:      
  profiles: dev
  datasource:    
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
    datasource:
    username: root
    password: root 
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
   
---
spring:      
  profiles: test
  datasource:    
    url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:scratchdb/db_name
    username: sa
    password:      
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

Comment: It is still using the properties from the application.properties, and not from application-test.properties

Comment: Do you want to use properties only from a single file? Then, you can opt for yml format where you can specify all the properties in a single file "application.yml".

Answer (score 1):

Well, your use case is very common and generally using In-memory is preferred when running locally.

Things required to activate it

1.Add below dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

you can get other H2 versions from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2)

2.Can have a local property file `application-local.properties` will following content

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

3.Activate local profile while running

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

OR

You can specify `spring.profiles.active` property in `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```